# Variable (eg.sinusoidal) fluidSource rate

Tags: javascript, anylogic

I'm setting up an activated sludge wastewater treatment plant model and I need to set the fluidSource flowrate to be a simple sinusoidal wave between 0 and 1. I want the wave to follow the number of seconds passed in the model.

I have tried using the formula `sin(time())+1`, but the `rate` option does not accept the input. Any help?

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

The rate is only assigned in the beginning of your simulation and is not updated dynamically as the simulation progresses.. to solve this... Create a cyclic event running every 1 milisecond for example and write down the following code:

```
fluidSource.set_rate(sin(time())+1);
```

Then your rate will change accordingly

[image: event]